# how to get unique column on the basis of reverse match id

Tags: mysql

| sender_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

it is a chat table and as it is showing that sender_id is sending message to receiver id now i want a unique list with the combination of two columns. so the result i am expecting after query implimentation is

| sender_id | receiver_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

i need a sql query for this. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try aggregating while using [`LEAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS person1, 
                GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id) AS person2
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYJsCQLtQb1MGF8waJtzFc/0).

---

If you need to take care of sender and receiver order, you may need to use a join operation then.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.sender_id, t1.receiver_id
FROM      tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2
       ON t1.sender_id = t2.receiver_id
      AND t1.receiver_id = t2.sender_id
WHERE t1.sender_id < t1.receiver_id 
   OR t2.sender_id IS NULL
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYJsCQLtQb1MGF8waJtzFc/3).

Comment: thanx , but it is exchanging column values 
the values should remain in their same column

Comment: You shouldn't eliminate `2, 1` then, otherwise we could arbitrarily have decided to keep `2, 1` in place of `1, 2`. What's the purpose of having column values in their original order?